# App ID - Alternative methods to confirm ownership

Tags: comobject

I have launched an app in IOS and android, however this app is from como.com which acts as a wrap around for our website (so we are a actually a website using como to hold us as an app).

I would like to make an app paid advert however I cannot install the required code because we do not own the app (only the website).  Is there are way for me to confirm ownership of the app as we are using a third party to host it?

Thank you for your time

Luke